# Redirect regex or htaccess url.com/city-randomcity/ to url.com/randomcity/

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, redirect

Is it possible to redirect multiple urls by keeping a part of the url or actually removing a part?

For example if I have a site with city guides for multiple cities with the url `loremipsum.com/guide-seattle` and I change all the urls to `loremipsum.com/seattle`

So I would want to create a redirect / rewrite rule with maybe regex saying if url is `/guide-randomcityname/` then remove `guide-` and keep `randomcityname` and redirect to `/randomcityname/`

A general rule for whatever the city name could be.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this redirect rule to remove `/guide-` from start of your URLs:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/guide-([^/]+/?)$ /$1
```